# HTML Image is deformed in Cordova/Phonegap App on Android

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an Android App with Cordova/Phonegap and it works fine! But I've got one problem. On most of the devices my logo at the top looks good and is displayed right:

[image: Good Logo]

But on some Android devices is the image deformed:

[image: Bad and deformed Logo]

The Image has the size of 200px x 50px and this size is defined in the HTML img-attribute and in the CSS file, too.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

[...]

<div id="topLogo">
    <center><img src="media/images/strikefm-logo-small-top.png" width="200" height="50" /></center>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#topFixed #topLogo {
    width:100%;
    height:62px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

#topFixed #topLogo img {
    position:relative;
    top:9px;
    width:200px !important;
    height:50px !important;
}
```

Does anyone knows a solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Share the img tag code, related css and the viewport meta tag code

Comment: try this viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />` And for better practice please use `width:200px` in inline css.